# Understanding Redirections in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, dotnetopenauth

How do redirections work in ASP.Net MVC?

I've copied and modified the [code bit from Scott Henselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode25OpenIDEdition.aspx) that uses DotNetOpenId to login via OpenID. Debugging, I find that when executing this code segment:

```
// Stage 2: user submitting Identifier
var openId = Request.Form["openId"];
new OpenIdRelyingParty().CreateRequest(openId).RedirectToProvider();
throw new Exception("Should never get here");
```

I never get to the throw clause, but rather continue with the redirection. How does that work?

Then, when I get the response from the OpenId provider, I'm debugging through this code segment:

```
switch (response.Status)
{
  case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(response.ClaimedIdentifier, false);
    // am I supposed to reach this line? What should I return here?
    // (The method expects a View to be returned)
```

And I find that the call to FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage() does return and I need to return something from the Action. What should I return here?

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, the `RedirectToProvider()` method calls the ASP.NET `Response.Redirect()` method.  This method, as implemented by ASP.NET itself, *throws an exception* (`ThreadAbortException` specifically).  That's why you never get to `throw new Exception("Should never get here");` line.  Note however that that although it is never reached, `throw` must still appear because it allows C# to know that no `return` statement is necessary for the method to be verifiable and safe code.

The `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` method also ultimately calls `Response.Redirect`, which means it also throws an exception.  But because you don't have a `throw` statement beneath it, C# requires that you return something instead.  When you're in a method with a return type, C# demands you return or throw at every possible exit point.

In ASP.NET web forms, `Response.Redirect` was your only option (well, not really but it seemed like it).  But ASP.NET MVC offers a RedirectAction that allows you to issue a browser redirect without ever throwing an exception.  And DotNetOpenAuth (the successor to DotNetOpenId) offers a way to leverage this feature.

As [shown here](http://trac.dotnetopenauth.net:8000/wiki/CodeSnippets/OpenIDRP/Programmatic) you can redirect to the provider by returning the result of `IAuthenticationRequest.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult()` from your controller's action to initiate login instead of calling `IAuthenticationRequest.RedirectToProvider()`.

Also, you can log the user into your site without using `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` by calling `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` and then `return Redirect(...)` within your controller's action to send the user onto his destination.

Comment: I find that FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage() does not throw an exception, but rather the execution does continue after it. What could cause this?

Comment: Hmmm... in that case that method may set `Response.RedirectLocation` property and just return, which will result in a redirect but not an exception, allowing the execution to continue.

Comment: But then what should I return from the controller action?

Comment: I suspect you can `return new EmptyAction()` and it (I think) should work.  If that doesn't work, well you can always `return Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] ?? FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl)` yourself.

Comment: There are two types of Response.Redirect, 1 is immediate and causes the thread abort exception, the other allows the request to continue executing but will send a redirect when finished. RedirectFromLoginPage uses Response.Redirect(url, false), Response.Redirect(url) is the same as Response.Redirect(url,true). The boolean parameter determines if the redirect is immediate.

Comment: You cannot return an `EmptyAction` and you must make sure `Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]` is not null and not empty.  You end up with  `return Redirect(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]) ? FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl : Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);`